# How can I split my dataset based on the labels in a different array?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

I am trying to split my dataset to train a neural network

Given 2 arrays (`dataset` and `Labels`)

`dataset` is a 3D array with a shape of (128,6,-1) while as `labels` is a 1d array containing the respective labels of `dataset`

Ex of data in labels `[0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]`

I want to split the data based on the labels with a 0.7- 0.3 ratio for my train and validation set.

I don't want to shuffle the data and want the following result
`trainLabels = [0,0,0,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2]` with their correposnding training data in the same index
and 
`evalLabel = [0,,1,2,2,2]` also with their corresponding training data in the same index.

Is there a function from pandas, numpy or scikit learn which allows me to do this?

I've tried `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split` but the dataset is shuffled

(An extra question not needed to answer: Can I just shuffle my dataset and split them? Are there negative effects?)

Comment: sklearn's `train_test_split` has an argument `shuffle` https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html

Comment: The problem is that when i use train_test_split with shuffle = False,
I just simply get a train dataset with labels [0 to 2 ] and a test dataset with labels 2

Comment: I want them balanced according to the ratio without shuffling the data

Comment: @Michael24 You can set the parameter `stratify = labels` to get balanced target in train and test. Yet this will necessarely shuffle your data.

Comment: @FBruzzesi thank you! I was worried about the data being shuffle before the partition, So it would create an unbalanced split at a different run instance. I'm okay with the data shuffling otherwise. I've tested the code again with your suggestion with a 50 50 ratio and the labels are balanced